# Clarification for UK Transit Without a Visa (TWOV) rules

Tags: schengen

My wife is from Kenya and meeting up with me in Spain for a vacation soon, using a Schengen visa. We will be touring in my car.

We also wish to visit friends in London briefly before catching the ferry to Dublin, Ireland.

Does my wife qualify for TWOV rules, (no U.K. Visa required), as we will be in the U.K. For less than 24 hrs?

Thank you.

Comment: The linked question will tell you about transit rules. But one of them is that for TWOV you must be arriving and departing by air.

Comment: Are you an EU citizen or a national of an EEA country or Switzerland?

Comment: Knowledgeable people: does it matter if she holds a visa for Ireland already? And doesn't the OP's citizenship matter?

Comment: DJClayworth you are wrong. There are two different TWOV situations. I'm not talking about the air travel one? If people are going to summit answers please make sure of your facts.

Answer (score 1):

No, she does not. According to [UK Visas and Immigration site](https://www.gov.uk/check-uk-visa/y/kenya/transit/republic_of_ireland) she will need to apply for a UK standard visitor visa.

Comment: My only edit was to fix the spelling on one word

Comment: Yes. I have British and Irish citizenship.